# Powell Plea Deal Consequences

Tags: criminal-law, lawyer, georgia, plea

Given Sidney Powell's plea deal: https://apnews.com/article/sidney-powell-plea-deal-georgia-election-indictment-ec7dc601ad78d756643aa2544028e9f5

The article indicates consequences:

> As part of the deal, she will serve six years of probation, will be
> fined $6,000 and will have to write an apology letter to Georgia and
> its residents. She also recorded a statement for prosecutors and
> agreed to testify truthfully against her co-defendants at future
> trials.

Said consequences seem trivial: her position seems precarious and the cost involved with a trial would dwarf the fine.

**Are there any other consequences not found in the article** (i.e. disbarred or the like)?

Comment: It *is* a slap on the wrist; that's the whole point.  The prosecution is deliberately and conspicuously letting her off easy, in exchange for her testimony against co-defendants who they are much more interested in convicting (i.e. Trump).

Comment: Also, if she pleads for guilty, it's more difficult for the co-defendants to argue that they're completely innocent and they knew of nothing.

Comment: Disbarrment and other disciplinary actions can only be enacted by the bar association at which the attorney is registered

Comment: the "agreed to testify" is the nail - she now **has** to testify, no step back, or she goes into jail.

Comment: Disbarment isn't a question that the criminal court decides. It is a separate determination of state attorney regulation officials. A felony conviction would usually result, at a minimum, in a suspension from the practice of law for a while, but whether or not the attorney is permanently disbarred for a moderately serious felony like this one could go either way.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella The bar association handles it in states with "integrated bar associations", in other states, the bar association is only a membership organization and bar admission is handled by the state judiciary separate from the bar association.

Answer (score 5):

### It’s a token punishment

But, I’m guessing that the testimony against others is more valuable to the prosecution than seeking a harsher penalty. Also, the relative leniency of this sentence may encourage others to flip. Plus, there’s no chance a jury might find her not guilty.

That said, it’s not unusual for star witnesses to be offered complete immunity, i.e. no punishment or conviction at all.

As for whether she can continue to be a lawyer, that’s for the bar associations in each state where she is licensed to practice. Criminal conviction is grounds for disbarment.